# how to change Sharepoint 2013 Default Sign-in Page and create Custom Page (normal.aspx) which redirects users to Http handler(test.ashx page)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth

Sharepoint Default Sign In page should redirect to my Custom HTTP Handler test.ashx code.

I configured multiple claim authentication in sharepoint server 2013 and I need to by pass multiple authentication drop down box in the de fault Sign In page.

Answer (score 0):

You may configure Form Based Authentication (see in the Authentication Providers page for the Web app in CA), and then edit the web.config file (on each WFE) to change the `loginUrl` property of the `<forms>` tag to point to your own page.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is working fine but I am redirecting to my custom HTTP handler https://spsxyz/_layouts/TestClaimhandler/Testhand.ashx

Using the below code, I am not getting Internet Explorer user name. It is throwing NULL object reference error




SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite ElevatedsiteColl = new SPSite(siteColl.ID))
   {
       using (SPWeb ElevatedSite = ElevatedsiteColl.OpenWeb(site.ID))
       {
            string currUser = site.CurrentUser; //not the ElevatedSite.CurrentUser
       }
   }
});

Comment: The `SPContext` is not initialized at this veru early stage of the request processing: you definitely cannot use it in the context of an authentication page. If your login page supports Windows authentication, you may use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to get the user name.

Comment: the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is throwing null value,
I am using in the below code

public partial class TestHand:IHttphandler{Public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
context.Response.write(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
}

Comment: is  there any other way to get Internet Explore logged user domain name

Comment: If I disabled Anonymous Authentication in IIS then I get Domain\\UserName, I configured ABC AD FS user Claims Based authentication in my sharepoint Page, If ABC User access the Custom HTTP Handler then it is prompting to XYZ sharepoint domain, how can I get other domain and user name when they login IE